# Non-existent user defined runtime attribute

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview

I have a simple Mac application that receives the following error when opening a document:
**Failed to set (allowsDragging) user defined inspected property on (PKMPDFView): [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key allowsDragging.**

If I intercept the "set" attempt, I see that it originates from the method **-[NSIBUserDefinedRuntimeAttributesConnector establishConnection]** during nib loading.

Full trace:

```
0   PDFApp                              0x0000000100003592 -[PKMPDFView setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 49
1   Foundation                          0x00007fff309b8dde -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 331
2   AppKit                              0x00007fff2c08af15 -[NSView setValue:forKeyPath:] + 394
3   AppKit                              0x00007fff2c00d029 -[NSIBUserDefinedRuntimeAttributesConnector establishConnection] + 637
4   AppKit                              0x00007fff2bdd9719 -[NSIBObjectData nibInstantiateWithOwner:options:topLevelObjects:] + 1430
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff2bdd0991 loadNib + 435
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff2bdcfeb5 +[NSBundle(NSNibLoading) _loadNibFile:nameTable:options:withZone:ownerBundle:] + 696
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff2c005aba +[NSBundle(NSNibLoadingInternal) _loadNibFile:externalNameTable:options:withZone:] + 150
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff2c005893 -[NSWindowController loadWindow] + 322
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff2be18cf5 -[NSWindowController window] + 84
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff2bfd8134 -[NSWindowController showWindow:] + 36
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff2be18c7a -[NSDocument showWindows] + 116
12  PDFApp                              0x0000000100002e75 -[PKMPDFDocument showWindows] + 50
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff2c35f13e __80-[NSDocumentController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:]_block_invoke.1039 + 182
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff2c36ef70 ___NSMainRunLoopPerformBlock_block_invoke + 25
15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2e897a3c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2e87a973 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 275
17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2e879ffe __CFRunLoopRun + 1278
18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2e879867 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 487
19  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff2db59d96 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 286
20  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff2db59b06 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 613
21  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff2db59884 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 64
22  AppKit                              0x00007fff2be09a73 _DPSNextEvent + 2085
23  AppKit                              0x00007fff2c59fe34 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 3044
24  AppKit                              0x00007fff2bdfe885 -[NSApplication run] + 764
25  AppKit                              0x00007fff2bdcda72 NSApplicationMain + 804
26  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff56848015 start + 1
```

What confuses me is that `PKMPDFView` is a direct subclass of `NSView` and has no user defined properties associated with it in the .xib file being loaded.  This view also has no outlets defined in the .xib, just a referencing outlet (contentView) from its document.  Running find/grep through my development directory finds no instance of "allowsDragging" anywhere.  Likewise, using the strings utility reveals no "allowsDragging" in the built app.

I've tried all the standard project cleaning with no change in symptoms.

At the moment, I'm tempted to simply override `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` and forget it but I'm still curious.  Does anyone have information or good guesses about where this would be coming from?

(This is Xcode 10.1 on macOS 10.13.6, in case that matters.)

Comment: I have no experience with Mac apps but this could happen if you drag something else than `NSView` to your Interface Builder and then you set the custom class to be `PKMPDFView`. Could you inspect the source of the xib and see how is `PKMPDFView` actually defined? Also check that there is no second reference set to the given view.

Comment: `allowsDragging` is a property of `PDFView`, could it be related? A mismatch somewhere because of manual changes?

Comment: @Larme Yes, I guess that it can happen if you drag `PDFView` and then change custom class to `PKMPDFView`. The nib then tries to set up the object with `PDFView` properties.

Comment: You're both right.  This is an app from 2015 that I just revisited and have no memory of why I thought a PDFView would be useful; the code certainly doesn't expect it.  In my defense, I believed the error message when it said "user defined".  :)